# HTTP Response Code: expected time between informational code (1xx) and non-informational code

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I am using a HttpURLConnection instance in order to connect to a URL.

I am then calling the getResponseCode method in order to determine the connection state.

I am polling the connection with this method, until the returned response-code is NOT 1xx:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(ref).openConnection();
int responseType = con.getResponseCode()/100;
while (responseType == 1)
{
    Thread.sleep(10);
    responseType = con.getResponseCode()/100;
}
switch (responseType)
{
    ...
}
```

What is the recommended time to sleep inside the loop? (here set to 10ms).

Is there any time period (min, max, average) defined in the HTTP standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status code "100 continue" is usually sent by the server after it got the request header of the POST request, to signal the client that it can follow up with the POST body. This way the server can reject requests early based on the request header (e.g. authorization required) without wasting resources on the client. The final response will then be sent after the server received the request body from the client, which might be immediately or hours later, depending on how fast the clients sends the request body.